# Google Dataproc cluster created via HTTP but not listed in SDK or viewer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am currently working on Google Cloud Platform to run Spark Jobs in the cloud. To do so, I am planning to use Google Cloud Dataproc.

Here's the work flow I am automatising :

- Upload a csv file on Google Cloud Storage which will be the input of my Spark job
- On upload, trigger a Google Cloud Functions which should create the cluster, submit a job and shutdown the cluster though the HTTP API available for Dataproc

I am able to create a cluster from my Google Cloud Function using the `google apis nodejs client` (http://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/latest/dataproc.html). But the problem is that I cannot see this cluster on the Dataproc cluster viewer or even by using the Gcloud sdk : `gcloud dataproc clusters list`.

However, I am able to see my newly created cluster on Google Api explorer : https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dataproc/v1/dataproc.projects.regions.clusters.list.

Note that I am creating my cluster in the current project.

What can I possibly do wrong not to be able to see that cluster when listing with gcloud sdk ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet it has to do with "region" field. Out of the box Cloud SDK defaults to "global" region [1]. Try using dataproc Cloud SDK commands with `--region` flag (e.g., `gcloud dataproc clusters list --region`)

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints

Comment: You're completely right ! As I do not have the possibility to select other regions on the viewer, I can't see it ...

Comment: FYI, Regional Endpoints just went GA end of last week and we're completing a phased rollout of the UI components for it this week, so very soon you should start seeing a dropdown menu for listing all the regional endpoints in the console UI